# C# Read HEX Serial Port Data and send to Streamwriter

Tags: c#, azure, serial-port, hex, streamwriter

I am trying to read serial data from a device which is sending its data in HEX and then write it to an azure relay streamwriter to a receiver application.
The device is sending these HEX Values : 16 51 1D 65 D4 A6
However my program seems to be reading:

:[image]

How do I get the serial port to read the HEX data and send it over a streamwriter? I have attached my code below. Thank you for your help!

```
// Read from the serial and write to the hybrid connection.
            var writes = Task.Run(async () => {
               // var reader = Console.In;
                var writer = new StreamWriter(relayConnection) { AutoFlush = true };
                
                
                do
                {
                    // Read serial data from the serial port.
                    string line = sp.ReadExisting();
                    // Write the line to the hybrid connection (Azure Relay)
                    if(line.ToString() != "")
                    { 
                        await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);

                    }

                    //cancel connection and break loop
                    if (Main.disconnect == true)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
                while (true);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read it as a byte array instead of text:

```
int length = sp.BytesToRead;
byte[] buf = new byte[length];

sp.Read(buf, 0, length);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received Data:" + buf);
```

Comment: Thank you, using your code i was able to acheive what i wanted! I have put my code below

Answer (score 1):

I solved my query with this code:

```
do
{
    // Read serial data from the serial port.
    //string line = sp.ReadExisting();
    int length = sp.BytesToRead;
    byte[] buf = new byte[length];
    sp.Read(buf, 0, length);
    // Write the line to the hybrid connection (Azure Relay)
    if(buf.ToString() != "")
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(buf[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        //await writer.WriteLineAsync(buf.ToString());
    
    }
```